# Need to query a self referencing table to find all items that are NOT the parent of any item

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query, self-reference

Like the title says, I need to query a self referencing table to find all items that are NOT the parent of any item.

My table is attached as an image link:

Here is my schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recursivebom`.`level` (
   `level` INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`level`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `recursivebom`.`item`

---

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recursivebom`.`item` (
   `itemNumber` INT NOT NULL,
   `quantity` DECIMAL NULL,
   `cost` DECIMAL NULL,
   `parentItem` INT NULL,
   `level` INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`itemNumber`, `level`),
   INDEX `fk_item_item1_idx` (`parentItem` ASC),
   INDEX `fk_item_level1_idx` (`level` ASC),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_item_item1`
     FOREIGN KEY (`parentItem`)
     REFERENCES `recursivebom`.`item` (`itemNumber`)
     ON DELETE NO ACTION
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `fk_item_level1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`level`)
     REFERENCES `recursivebom`.`level` (`level`)
     ON DELETE NO ACTION
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: link to table image: http://imgur.com/elKkUEn

Comment: What is the output you want/are getting?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   item
WHERE  itemNumber NOT IN (SELECT parentItem FROM item)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot, but the query does not return any records.

Comment: @user3590335 Can you please create an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for your tables? According to the provided image, this *should* have worked.